# What is the difference between starting address and slave address in MODBUS?

Tags: communication, modbus, modbus-tcp

I read a lot of documentation but could not find any satisfying answer to clear my confusion.

Answer (score 3):

*Starting address* can mean two different things. It may refer to the first address of a specific Modbus slave table e.g. holding registers start at address 40001. Or it may refer to the first address when reading for example multiple holding registers.

*Slave address* is the unique unit address from 1 to 247, better known as *Slave ID*. Alternatively, it can also be used as a synonym for the slave’s IP address I suppose.

Comment: any examples you know?

Comment: Modbus table _Starting address_ is for example used [here](https://www.rtautomation.com/technologies/modbus-rtu/). _Starting address_ when reading for example multiple holding registers is used in the Modbus spec www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_Application_Protocol_V1_1b.pdf, see paragraph 6.3.

Comment: suppose I have a 8 bit digital I/O module and I want to control all of them with modbus coils, then any example, what would be the slave and and what would be the starting address?

Comment: [IO device example](https://www.bqtek.com/en/download/bq351-user-manual.pdf) where the _slave address_ can be set with switches and a coil table where every register can be a _starting addess_ when writing multiple coils (function code 16).